# how to get bytearray from Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am working with Camera2 API i am struck at getting the byte array of the Live frame, any one please help me in getting the solution

the following code gives only at one instance the byte array for getting the live feed byte array(i.e.12 frames Per second)

```
 ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

                Image image = null;
                try {
                    image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                    buffer.get(bytes);
                    save(bytes);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (image != null) {
                        image.close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What parameters are you using to create the ImageReader?  I'm guessing you're using ImageFormat.JPEG, given that you're looking looking at plane 0 of the image.

Comment: I am using the width height and image format

Comment: Yes, those are mandatory arguments. What values are you using?